# Bad JDBC select performance with big table

Tags: postgresql, performance, jdbc

I have a simple select on a big table with PostgreSQL:

```sql
select a, b from c order by id asc
```

I prepare a statement with JDBC and the first result takes very long. It seems that the result is materialized fully immediately. If I execute the query interactively it shows the same behavior. If I add `limit 20`, the result comes immediately, so there is no indexing or full table scan:

```sql
select a, b from c order by id asc Limit 20
```

Normally, the ResultSet is accessed with a cursor and should immediately deliver results. Also, the memory consumption grows constantly during the query execution, supporting the thesis that the ResultSet is materialized immediately.

Any hints about that?

Comment: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/query.html#query-with-cursor

Comment: That was it - thank you very much!